# VBA follow hyperlink in module level

Tags: vba, excel

I need to have a simple hyperlink (on any sheet), which when clicked displays a message. Placing this code in a module is required, so using the applicable sheet or workbook isn't an option.

When the code is in any applicable worksheet - it works:

```
Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)  
    Msgbox "It works!"  
End Sub
```

When the code is in ThisWorkbook - it works:

```
Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)  
    MsgBox "It Works!"  
End Sub
```

I've tried the following in a module - it *doesn't* work:

```
Sub Application_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)  
    MsgBox "No Such Luck :("  
End Sub
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for helping a newbie out.

Comment: Why don't you want it in the sheet code are or the thisworkbook code area?

Comment: I am programatically inserting a module from a save .BAS file, which will happen across a number of workbooks. AFAIK, I am unable to insert code in this fashion into either the worksheet-level or workbook-level code.

Comment: `I am unable to insert code in this fashion` Why? What problems are you facing? You can always read the data from tha bas file and insert it in the `ThisWorkbook` Code area.

Comment: Siddarth, I'm using the code demonstrated here [link] http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/copy-vba-module.php though am unsure how to go about inserting it into the ThisWorkbook code area as you've suggested.

Comment: Ok one moment... Posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you Bas file looks like this

[image]

**Pre Requirements:**

1. Set an reference to the VBA Extensibility library. In the VBA editor, go the the Tools menu and choose References and select Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3

   [image]
2. You need to enable programmatic access to the VBA Project. Developer Tool Bar | Macro Security item in the Code panel. In that dialog, choose Macro Settings and check the Trust access to the VBA project object model.

   [image]

**Code: In a module**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MyBasFile As String
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String

    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum As Long, i As Long

    '~~> path to your Bas File
    MyBasFile = "D:\Users\SidzPc\Desktop\Sample.Bas"

    '~~. Open Bas File as text and read it in one go into memory
    Open MyBasFile For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    '~~> Store the conteents in array
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    '~~> Define Destination - Thisworkbook
    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    With CodeMod
        LineNum = 1
        '~~> Loop Through array and write to thisworkbook code area
        For i = 1 To UBound(strData) - 1
            Debug.Print strData(i)
            .InsertLines LineNum, strData(i)
            LineNum = LineNum + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output When you run the above code**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use worksheet-level code to trap the event and have that sub call a module-level sub to perform the bulk of the processing.

The advantage of this approach is that you do not have to maintain multiple copies of coding for each sheet.

Comment: `The advantage of this approach is that...` Gary, I thought of that but then for that you could you use `Application_SheetFollowHyperlink` :) And hence my question below the OP's post.